# Oracle query to display multiple row in one column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

New to oracle. I will always have 2 rows in DB. I need to display result in one row

**DB Data**

```
EmployeeType  Salary Department

Permanent        1000     Science
Contractor       1500     Maths
```

**Expected Output**

```
EmployeeTypeOne   SalaryOne  DepartmentOne E mployTypeeTwo  Salarytwo  Departmenttwo

Permanent            1000         Science         Contractor        1500       Maths
```

Comment: read up on PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

You may use max + case logic as follows

```
 select max('Permanant') as EmployeeTypeOne
       ,max(case when EmployeeType='Permanant' then Salary end ) as SalaryOne  
       ,max(case when EmployeeType='Permanant' then Department end ) as DepartmentOne
       ,max('Contractor') as EmployeeTypeTwo
       ,max(case when EmployeeType='Contractor' then Salary end ) as SalaryTwo
       ,max(case when EmployeeType='Contractor' then Department end ) as DepartmentTwo
from <table>
```

Comment: Need a solution that work when there are two rows of EmployeeType = 'Permanent' .TIA

Comment: Supposing with two types, what should the order of te columns. There is no first record/last recrod in database tables. The solution ofr this would be to  build the query string and then execute the query if there is going to be random number of rows

Comment: Was looking to order by salary.